# Oracle 12C SQL Aggregate Query Logic

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, aggregate-functions

I need help in writing SQL query for below mixed aggregation scenario:
Consider below Emp Table. Need to aggregate employee records by manager.

Aggregaton Logic:
Need top Rating under manager. 
Eg. for Mgr 10, Rating should be Super , For 30, Good

Need EmpDesig and Dob for emp with least rating.
Sal and Bonus should be aggregated by Sum().

```
   Mgr Emp Rating  EmpSal EmpDesig Bonus     Dob
   10  11   Avg      1000   JE        50   Jan-85
   10  12   Good     1500   SE        30   Mar-85
   10  12   Super    2000   ASE       60   Mar-84
   20  21   Good     1000   SE        40   Apr-85
   20  22   Avg      1000   AST       45   Dec-86
   30  31   Good     500    SE        80   Oct-85
   30  32   Good     1000   ASE       70   Jan-87
   30  33   Avg      1500   ASC       90   Nov-85
   30  34   Avg      500    JE       20    Jan-89
```

So Output for above Dataset should be

```
   Mgr Rating  EmpSal EmpDesig Bonus     Dob
   10   Super    4500   JE       140   Jan-85
   20   Good     2000   AST      85    Dec-86
   30   Good     3500   JE       260   Jan-89

       Create table emp(MgrID number, EmpID number, varchar2(30),EmpSal number, EmpDesig 
      varchar2(30),
      Bonus number,    Dob varchar2(30));
      insert into emp values (10,  11,   'Avg',      1000,   'JE',        50,   'Jan-85');
      insert into emp values (10,  12,   'Good',     1500,   'SE',        30,   'Mar-85');
      insert into emp values (10,  12,   'Super',    2000,   'ASE',       60,   'Mar-84');
      insert into emp values (20,  21,   'Good',     1000,   'SE',        40,   'Apr-85');
      insert into emp values (20,  22,   'Avg',      1000,   'AST',       45,   'Dec-86');
      insert into emp values (30,  31,   'Good',     500,   'SE',        80,   'Oct-85');
      insert into emp values (30,  32,   'Good',    1000,   'ASE',       70,   'Jan-87');
      insert into emp values (30,  33,   'Avg',      1500,   'ASC',       90,   'Nov-85');
      insert into emp values (30,  34,   'Avg',      500,   'ASC',       90,   'Jan-89');
```

I tried building logic with below query but could not.

```
   Select mgr, 
    max(rating) over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 1 when 'Good' then 2 
    when 'Avg' then 3 end) rating,
    row_number () over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 1 when 'Good' then 2 
    when 'Avg' then 3 end) rating_rnk,
    sum(empSal),
    sum(bonus),
    max(empdesig) over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 3 when 'Good' then 2 
    when 'Avg' then 1 end) empdesig,
    row_number () over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 3 when 'Good' then 2 
    when 'Avg' then 1 end) empdesig_rnk,

    max(dob) over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 3 when 'Good' then 2 when 
    'Avg' then 1 end) dob,
     row_number () over (partition by mgr order by case Rating when 'Super' then 3 when 'Good' then 
     2 when 'Avg' then 1 end) dob_rnk
    from 
    emp
    group by mgr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is conditional aggregation.  I think the key is to enumerate the ratings:

```
SELECT mgrid,
    (
        CASE MIN(rating_order)
            WHEN 1   THEN 'Super'
            WHEN 2   THEN 'Good'
            WHEN 3   THEN 'Avg'
        END
    ) AS max_rating,
    MAX(empdesig) KEEP (dense_rank first order by rating_order desc, empid) AS empdesig,
    MAX(dob) KEEP (dense_rank first order by rating_order desc, empid) AS dob,
    SUM(empsal) AS sal, 
    SUM(bonus)
FROM (SELECT e.*, 
         (
             CASE rating
                 WHEN 'Super' THEN 1
                 WHEN 'Good' THEN 2
                 WHEN 'Avg' THEN 3 end ) as rating_order
             FROM emp e
         ) e GROUP BY mgrid;
```